# Как обновить модели CoreML в приложении iOS через парсинг JSON, разработанном на Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile-development, uikit

В моем приложении используются фильтры моделей CoreML. Через парсинг JSON-файла я планирую обновлять список моделей (Загружать по ссылке из JSON, добавлять, а так же удалять модели CoreML).

Вопрос: как в собранном приложении (опубликованном в AppStore) через парсинг JSON обновить модели (добавить новые или удалить уже имеющиеся)?

Comment: Через URLSession или через Alamofire... Уточни вопрос? Ты хочешь увидеть потенциальную архитектуру приложения или ссылку на мануал по использованию сети?

Comment: @MorganFreewalker Если честно - любой материал, который поможет

Comment: В таком случае я бы сделал следующую структуру: 1) Получение списка моделей в json-формате (типа ключей Имя-Размер-Ссылка) 2) При выборе пользователем модели начиналась бы скачка через URLSession и сохранялась с помощью FileManager. 3) При необходимости уже подгружалась бы модель из локального файла